# Reflecting user's negative feedback in training data

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning

I am trying out Amazon Personalize machine learning service to create a movie recommendation system.
I can import my dataset in the following format:

```
USER_ID,ITEM_ID,EVENT_TYPE,EVENT_VALUE,TIMESTAMP
```

My dataset is consist of histories of likes and dislikes by users.
What I am confused about is how I should reflect the nature of the event in my dataset, event being positive (A like) or negative (A dislike)

These are the predefined recipes that Amazon uses to train a model:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/working-with-predefined-recipes.html

Comment: I have just faced the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I talked to the support and it seems like that we have to filter out the data and only upload positive feedback. I also saw an example on AWS blog about a movie recommendation system and they suggested to only submit 4+ ratings to the system and filter out any ratings below 4 (for a 1 to 5 start system).

Comment: Wow. It is surprisingly dumb that they did not write it explicitly in documentation. Thank you! Do you have a link to your chat with support?

Comment: The documentation leaves a lot to be desired overall.  I am hoping they address that first thing.